# KVM Build - Team with Native VLAN and Tagged VLANs

Tags: kvm-virtualization, vlan, bridge

I'm trying to get clarity on whether or not what I have been trying to do is possible since I have yet to get this working.  I have a server in a lab with two NICs that I would like to team.  I then want to use the native VLAN to work as a management interface, and add two additional VLANs to present to VMs in KVM.  I'm using Fedora 26 and nmcli to build the configuration.

My current attempt flows like this:

MGMT Interface (VLAN 2)

> eth0/eth1 -> team0 -> br0 - (IP Assigned to br0 and working)

VLAN Interfaces

> eth0/eth1 -> team0 -> VLAN3 -> br0.3 -> KVM - (Not working)

When using nmcli to build the bridge for the vlan, I did notice that "brctl show" does not have the VLAN2 interface as part of the bridge.  brctl does allow me to manually add it, but when I then add the bridge to KVM, VMs can not communicate on the network.

```
#brctl show br0.3
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
br0.3       8000.000000000000   yes
```

So a few questions:

1. Is my method correct in how I would map the interfaces?
2. I've seen people comment that scenarios like this will not work with teaming
   and I should use a bond...is this true?
3. Could nmcli be an issue? I notice it adds a lot of additional configurations to the ifcfg files that I wonder if they could be causing me issues.  I've also see people in the past outright disable NetworkManager because of issues, is it still "flaky."

Here are the config files that nmcli created.  Teaming is working and the ip associated with the bridge for that team is working as well:

**ifcfg-team0**

```
DEVICE=team0
TEAM_CONFIG="{\"runner\":{\"name\":\"loadbalance\",\"tx_hash\":    [\"eth\",\"ipv4\",\"ipv6\"],\"tx_balancer\":{\"name\":\"basic\"}}}"
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
NAME=team0
UUID=712b6eea-5556-4c3b-b9cd-1b23bd782cac
ONBOOT=yes
DEVICETYPE=Team
BRIDGE=br0
```

**ifcfg-team0-port1**

```
NAME=team0-port1
UUID=9c4fa0f1-aef0-4c23-ae2b-5b5de0cbe17b
DEVICE=enp0s31f6
ONBOOT=yes
TEAM_MASTER=team0
DEVICETYPE=TeamPort
```

**ifcfg-team0-port2**

```
NAME=team0-port2
UUID=8dd9a749-a7d2-4247-8d0a-999fbf7d76ee
DEVICE=enp8s0
ONBOOT=yes
TEAM_MASTER=team0
DEVICETYPE=TeamPort
```

**ifcfg-br0**

```
DEVICE=br0
STP=yes
BRIDGING_OPTS=priority=32768
TYPE=Bridge
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
BOOTPROTO=static
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=no
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=stable-privacy
NAME=br0
UUID=f22ce071-72bf-4b76-9293-f75ddc4ef137
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=192.168.1.200
PREFIX=24
GATEWAY=192.168.1.1
```

**ifcfg-team0.3**

```
VLAN=yes
TYPE=Vlan
DEVICE=team0.3
PHYSDEV=enp0s3
VLAN_ID=3
REORDER_HDR=yes
GVRP=no
MVRP=no
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
IPV6INIT=no
NAME=team0.3
UUID=830d4593-dfc1-4b36-93b4-cc00a29b45ff
ONBOOT=yes
```

**ifcfg-br0.3**

```
DEVICE=br0.3
STP=yes
BRIDGING_OPTS=priority=32768
TYPE=Bridge
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
IPV6INIT=no
NAME=br0.3
UUID=2551f354-25f2-41c9-955e-73b352e0f033
ONBOOT=yes
```

edit:
Made some progress, was able to get the vlan add to the bridge by running:

> nmcli con mod team0.3 connection.slave-type bridge connection.master br0.3

However, I still can't get the VMs in KVM to successfully use the network.

**Edit**
So I have determined that the issue is with the bridge and not the team.  If I remove the team and bridge a single ethernet connection, the bridge works.  As soon as I do the same for the team, it no longer seems to forward packets.

Also, I realized that my native vlan port is VLAN 2 (MGMT) so I changed this to a tagged port to simplify the trunk port.  Now all vlans I'm trying to use are tagged.  They do get IP addresses if I use DHCP, but the traffic is not forwarded.

Can anyone please tell me what I can do to check the bridge?

Thanks
Ray

Comment: Instead of creating vlan interfaces, you can simply use bridge br0 and create kvm guests with tagged vlans.
Your management will be untagged and vms will be tagged, both will pass through same interface.

Comment: Thanks Paresh, but the issue is not with the vlan but with the bridge.  When I exclude plans from the config, I still can't get an IP on the VM.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to get this working with bonding but not teaming.  My issue with bonding was a misconfigured switch; certain modes need to have trunk ports.  Teaming, however does not seem to be compatible with bridging and thus KVM.  Works on the host, but I was not able to present networks to my guest VMs.